# Can anyone give me x,y coordinates for an octagon?

Tags: polygons

I am looking to draw a octagon and I need $(x, y)$ coordinates.

Comment: does it need to be a regular octagon (all sides the same length and all angles the same angle measure)?

Comment: That would be great, if all sides are same like a STOP sign.

Comment: So, yes, a regular octagon. That is an important part of the problem. Otherwise it might look like a lightning bolt that happens to have 8 sides, or something else crazy

Comment: Can you live with coordinates that are irrational?

Comment: hmmm, initially I am ok.

Comment: @mweiss they have to be. You cant draw a regular octagon without that can you?

Comment: @Asimov Yes, I know.  But I wasn't sure if the OP was aware and okay with that.  Perhaps what he wants is just something that is approximately correct, say to two digits precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are most easily done using a rotation matrix:
$$R = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array}\right]$$
So that if you have a coordinate $\left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ y\end{array}\right]$, the vector $$R\left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ y\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta \\ x\sin\theta +y\cos\theta\end{array}\right]$$
is $\left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ y\end{array}\right]$ rotated $\theta$ radians counterclockwise around the origin.

Now suppose one vertex of your octagon is at $(1,0)$. To get the second vertex, you should rotate this by $\frac{2\pi}{8} = \frac{\pi}{4}$. And to get the third vertex, you rotate the second by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and so on. This is a general solution that you can utilize to find the coordinates (e.g. using a computer) for any regular $n$-gon.

An regular octagon is special in the sense that you will get the simple expression
$$(1,0),(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}), (0,1), (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}), (-1,0), (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}), (0, -1), (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$
for its coordinates.

Edit: To get the coordinates for a "real" stop sign, you will need to start from the point $(\cos \frac{\pi}{8}, \sin\frac{\pi}{8})$.

Comment: Well, that's more thorough than my answer. The only thing is, is it perhaps too advanced for someone just trying to get the points for an octagon? Just trying to be realistic here.

Comment: @Asimov Perhaps. Let's hope it will help the OP. Depending on his desired orientation of the stop sign, he may need to rotate everything by $\pi/8$ anyway (check for example a "real" stop sign.). In that case, he will need these rotation matrices for sure.

Comment: I hope it does. Indeed, it does have more generalized use. It is a good technique, but if perchance the OP isnt used to vector form, or the use of these matrices, or sine and cosine to rotate, then perhaps a simpler geometric approach using 45 degree right angles would work better. Still, your answer is worthy of a +1

Comment: Yeah, This is what I am looking for :). Thanks Alott!!!

Comment: Yeah, I left it yesterday. I am all set its working like a charm. Selected as answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that x,y koordinates of an regular n-gon:

$x=\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n}),\,\,\, y=\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n}),\,\,\, k = 1,2,3\cdots n$

So for octagon n = 8.

Answer (score 0):

So, it the side length is $1$, and each edge is at a $135$ degree angle from each other, then the width of the total octagon is $1+\sqrt{2}$ Does this give you enough information to start calculating the points?

Comment: The height and width are the same, so it should be reasonable straightforward if you draw it out. Comment back if you need some specific help.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a *regular* octogon, solve $x^8 = 1$. Then, if required, apply any homothetic transformation and/or rotation to the obtained set of points.

Cheers.